# Using 'that' & 'what' in following sentences

Tags: grammar

Why is the sentence below wrong?

> You cannot buy all what you like!

And instead, why is the sentence below right?

> You cannot buy all that you like!

I saw this at https://www.engvid.com/english-resource/50-common-grammar-mistakes-in-english/

Comment: Because "what" is not ordinarily allowed in relative clauses.

Comment: *What* is uncommon phrasing, and it's unidiomatic. However, it's not outright *wrong*. (It used to be used.) But I certainly wouldn't expect to use it and not be corrected.